# Headcount that includes leavers

Tags: reporting-services, ssms

I'm using SSMS and SSRS 2018. I need to create a Headcount Report in SSRS. Ideally it will have 2 date parameters @DateFrom and @DateTo where we can count how many people were employed in the business between certain dates, leavers will need to be included if they were still in employment between the dates chosen. Below is the dataset

```
ID      Name         ContractStart     ContractEnd       Department      status  
1       Bob Masters   2013-07-01       2013-07-23          ICT           Leaver
1       Bob Masters   2013-07-24       2018-01-02          BIT           Leaver
2       Kate Williams 2021-02-01       NULL                Stores        Active
3       Sam Power     2015-03-02       2016-05-01          ICT           Active
3       Sam Power     2016-05-02       2018-03-01          ICT           Active
3       Sam Power     2018-03-02       NULL                ICT           Active
4       Becky Smith   2021-09-10       NULL                Finance       Active
5       Debbie Glover 2019-11-11       2020-01-01          HR            Leaver
5       Debbie Glover 2020-06-07       2022-01-01          HR            Leaver 
6       Helen Stewart 2020-02-05       NULL                ICT           Active
6       Helen Stewart 2021-04-09       NULL                Stores        Active
7       Izzy Andrews  2017-06-10       2022-10-01          HR            Active
```

Things to note

- ID 6 has 2 open contracts so would need to be counted twice
- ID 7 is currently still active, though has an end date in the future

Ideally need help with the parameter as I'm only used to dealing with the example below

```
Where date between @datefrom and @dateto
```

Comment: There was no release of SSRS in 2018 and SSMS has very little to do with SSRS. Uou can connect to an SSRS instance from SSMS, sure, but all you can do is see what reports are currently being run and look at the schedules; I'm not sure what that has to do with the qeustion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the datefrom is before the contract end date (or the contract end date is NULL), and the dateto should be after the contract start date:

```
WHERE (@datefrom <= ContractEnd  OR ContractEnd IS NULL)        
AND @dateto >= ContractStart;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Count(*) as ActiveEmployeeCount
    FROM 
        (SELECT ID, Name, ContractStart, EndDate = ISNULL(ContractEnd, '9999-01-01'), Department, [status] FROM myTable) a 
    WHERE (a.ContractStart <= @DateTo and EndDate >= @DateFrom)
```

Comment: Only noticed after I posted my answer that Wouter had already come up with an answer which is virtually identical.